# method signature in inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

In the code below

```
class A {
    public void v(int... vals) {
        System.out.println("Super");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    @Override
    public void v(int[] vals) {
        System.out.println("Sub");
    }
}
```

Then I can call `new B().v(1, 2, 3);//print Sub rather than Super` which is ridiculous but **does work well**. If I change `B` to

```
class B {
    public void v(int[] vals) {
        System.out.println("Not extending A");
    }
}
```

the call to `new B().v(1, 2, 3);` will be invalid. You have to call it as `new B().v(new int[]{1, 2, 3});`, why?

Comment: A simple understanding of Java inheritance and overloading could explain this...  If Class B doesn't extend Class A, then Class B can't do the method specifically written in Class A.

Comment: @MohammadS.what is magic here is the method v(int[]) in B actually overrides the method v(int...) in a~ So although the signature of v in B is v(int[]), it still can be called using v(1, 2, 3)

Comment: Note that your first version doesn't work for me with JDK 7. Which Java compiler are you using?

Comment: Ahhh ok.  How are you compiling this?  It doesn't compile for me.

Comment: java version "1.6.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_51-b11-456-11M4508)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.51-b01-456, mixed mode)

Comment: It doesn't work for me with Eclipse either. Basically I think you've found a bug in JDK 1.6 which was fixed in JDK 1.7.

Comment: Can we see the exact code you're running?  It may not be a solely a JDK 1.6 bug.

Comment: I've just reproduced the bug on JDK 6 myself. (The same code compiles in Java 7 and Eclipse.)

Comment: I can compile and run the code using emacs + javac + java but I can't compile it using eclipse~ There will be a red cross~

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under JDK 1.7, *neither* of your examples compiles, and I don't believe they should.

It's easy to see why the second version doesn't - when `B` doesn't extend `A`, there's no indication of varargs at all, so there's no reason why the compiler should possibly convert an argument list of three `int` arguments into a single `int[]`. The more interesting situation is where `B` *does* extend `A`.

The compiler finds a signature of `v(int[] vals)` which *doesn't* use varargs. There's nothing in the spec to say it should look up the inheritance chain to find whether one of the other declarations (there could be multiple ones) uses varargs. The fact that it appears to in your version of JDK 1.6 suggests that was a compiler bug which has since been fixed. (I've just reproduced the bug in JDK 1.6.0_39 as well.)

Basically, if you want to be able to invoke `B.v()` in a varargs-style syntax, `B.v()` should be declared using varargs. Of course, if you change it so that the compile-time type is `A`, that would work:

```
A a = new B();
a.v(1, 2, 3);
```

Or even (ick):

```
((A) new B()).v(1, 2, 3);
```

Note that if you compile with `-Xlint` you get a warning about `B` anyway:

```
Test.java:14: warning: v(int[]) in B overrides v(int...) in A; overriding method
 is missing '...'
    public void v(int[] vals) {
                ^
```

Comment: I didn't get a.v(1,2,3) part? Where does this a come from?

Comment: @Nambari: It's the version of `v` declared in `A`, which uses varags: `v(int... vals)`

Comment: Actually in the first situation, B a = new B(); a.v(1, 2, 3); will also work well

Comment: @charles_ma: Ah, that does surprise me. Will investigate.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work work because of the way vararg works.

If your method is:

```
foo(int... par)

foo(new int[]{1, 2, 3});
foo(1, 2, 3);
```

These are both valid method calls. However, it doesn't work the other way around.

If your method is:

```
bar(int[] par)

bar(new int[]{1, 2, 3}); // Valid
bar(1, 2, 3); // Invalid!
```

The second call will be invalid. If the method has a vararg parameter, it can accept an array; if it has an array parameter, it can only accept an array, not a sequence of parameters!